# Tcp connection packets ignoring network delays, ping shows delays

Tags: tcp, openwrt, icmp

I've introduced a 2000ms latency to all network packets using openwrt [netem](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem) module.

```
# This is run on the terminal of the OpenWRT router
tc qdisc add dev wlan1 root netem delay 2000ms
```

I can clearly see the effects of this when pinging devices in the network.

```
# ping 192.168.10.164
PING 192.168.10.164 (192.168.10.164): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.10.164: seq=0 ttl=64 time=2001.956 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.164: seq=1 ttl=64 time=2010.677 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.164: seq=2 ttl=64 time=2004.216 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.164: seq=3 ttl=64 time=2001.451 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.164: seq=4 ttl=64 time=2005.981 ms
```

However if I attempt to notice this delay while exchanging messages via `nc`, it seems to be ignored.

```
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|    Terminal 1       |   Terminal 2                   |     
|   (192.168.10.164)  |   192.168.10.186               |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|  # nc -l 2389       |                                |
|                     | # nc 192.168.10.164 2389       |
|                     |      Hello                     |
|  # NO 2s DELAY      |                                |
|  # ALMOST INSTANT   |                                |
|    Hello            |                                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
```

My questions are:

- If it's just an case of a miss-configured `netem` module, what would be toe correct one which would apply delays on all IP packets?

*Update*
This seems to be caused by a bug in the netem module. After the router restart and replying the commands I am experiencing the expected delay.

Comment: did you introduce the delay *both* ways? or only one way? Wouldn't be seen with ping since it's always measuring the delay sum of both ways.

Answer (score 0):

ICMP and TCP are different protocols and if your command affects ICMP packets, it would not affect TCP packets.

Comment: You're right. That didn't make sense to ask. Deleted the question.

Comment: The thing is that `tc` should affect *all* packets.

Answer (score 0):

The docummenation of netem is nice here (https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem), on the other hand, did you check that the interfaces are correct, in general the opewwrt creates network devices and you are reffering to wlan to netem and may be the nc process are on a different network associated a different device

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you added the qdisc on `192.168.10.164` and when you ping from 186 you get a 2-second delay because of the response time and not because of the request time.

For your netcat, the `Hello` flows from 186 -> 164 and that doesn't go through the netem qdisc (because it is input to the interface). But if you notice closer, you should be able to see a 2-second delay when opening the connection.

You should be able to see the delay if you type the other way around.

Regarding the reboot, is there a chance that you did the test the other way around after the reboot? I.e. typed on 164 instead of 186?